# System.Reactive.Testing.TestScheduler for System.Threading.Task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I have used `System.Reactive.Testing.TestScheduler` to test asynchronous code implemented using `Observables` before.

I have now written code that uses `Task.Run` `async/await`, and `Task.Delay(...)` statements, and would like to have similar funcionality to the `TestScheduler`.

For Example, I would like to control time like I can with `TestScheduler.AdvanceBy()`.

How would you do that in that case?

Answer (score 1):

It sure seems like this should be a NuGet package somewhere...

What I did when I had this same problem recently is to take inspiration from Polly's `SystemClock`: define some (`internal`) delegates for calls like `Task.Delay` and redirect them to my own test implementation in my tests. If you have a VS SKU that supports Microsoft Fakes, you can skip that step and just hook `Task.Delay` directly.

In my case I kept a collection of `TaskCompletionSource` instances (and `CancellationTokenSource` instances), and used an Rx-like `AdvanceTo` to complete them.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried finding such a library, but was not successful. Would you be so kind to point me to one if you are aware of such a library?

Comment: @Ynv: I haven't found one, either.